# How to change div position from fixed to absolute when browser size is small

Tags: html, browser, resize, position, fixed

I need to change my div position from fixed to absolute when browser size is smaller than 1000px. How to do that? should I use jquery?
I give you a piece of my css file.

```
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
height: 100px;
min-width: 800px;
top: 0px;
right: 0px;
left: 0px;
z-index: 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it  out, it goes something like that. Maybe it will help somebody.

```
    window.onresize = function() {
if ($(window).width() < 1195) {$("#logo , #lingiriba").css("position" , "absolute");}
if ($(window).width() > 1194) {$("#logo , #lingiriba").css("position" , "fixed");}

}
```